# Why should we create one interface for this configuration class?

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-core, design-patterns, .net-core

My understanding of interfaces is that they define contracts and classes implementing the interface sign the contract. In that case, we may design classes to depend on the contract and not on the concrete implementation. This has advantages like reducing coupling, enabling polymorphism, and so forth.

Now I have came across one use of interfaces which I didn't get. This is from the ASP.NET Core documentation, regarding configuration. In particular, [in the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), one is talking about setting up MongoDB with ASP.NET Core.

They basically define a class and an interface like this:

```
namespace BooksApi.Models
{
    public class BookstoreDatabaseSettings : IBookstoreDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string BooksCollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBookstoreDatabaseSettings
    {
        string BooksCollectionName { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then they use this as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>(
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(BookstoreDatabaseSettings)));

    services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

    services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

I must say I gon't get it. The objects of type `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` are meant to work as DTOs for the settings. They don't provide any functionality at all. So why introduce one interface in the middle?

I don't see here one usage on which one would use some other implementation. I don't see here why one is trying to decouple this, I don't see any use of polymorphism at all, and I really didn't get the point.

So why in this situation, when dealing with settings in ASP.NET Core, one uses interfaces and not the concrete class (for example `BookstoreDatabaseSettings`) directly?

Comment: Tbh, this is probably leftovers from a dev who worked in full .Net Framework. Back then, the configuration settings lived in App.config files and defining a custom section required annoying XML annotations and inheriting a base type. So to workaround this for UT purposes, we'd defined interfaces. With POCO config in .Net core you're right, there's basically no reason to not use just a class.

Comment: Could also be to make it more 'future proof'. As example; maybe you will add a method in the future `GetSettings` that connects to an external database, which you'll likely want to mock in a unit test.

Comment: It would make sense if interface has only getters, but since that's not the case, you can omit it completely.

Answer (score 9):

In the context of just one app, you're correct that this doesn't make sense. However, there could be scenarios where it might.

What's happening here is that, first, the `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` is bound to the config section. This is technically all that's required. However, this uses the options pattern, which mean that you must then injnect `IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>`, `IOptionsSnapshot<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>` etc., rather than `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` directly. That implies a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`, which is not necessary a bad thing, but it is a dependency nonetheless.

The next line then binds the interface to the actual `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` instance, pulled from `IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>`. In other words, you can now simply inject the interface, instead of `IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings`. Again, nothing monumental, but it abstracts the use of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`. For what it's worth, you could have just as easily registered `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` instead of the interface to get the same thing. Then, you'd be able to inject `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` directly, without a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`.

What the interface buys you here, is abstracting the actual class implementation. You could potentially put the interface alone in a library that's shared between projects, and leave the actual class implementation to each individual project. If your shared libraries depend only on the interface, then the actual implementation that's provided won't matter. However, you could just as easily share the class implementation between projects as well. It's just a matter of perspective.

Comment: Potentially. I mean ultimately, any answer from anyone other than who actually wrote the code the OP is referencing is nothing more than speculation. However, I think in general, the question is more why you might choose to use an interface, which is a bit more objective.